# Should Python's property() be used as a decorator or saved to a variable?

Tags: python, properties, decorator

Which is the preferred way to use the Python built-in function [property()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property)? As a decorator or saved to a variable?

Here's an example saving `property()` to a variable `color`.

```
class Train(object):
    def __init__(self, color='black'):
        self._color = color

    def get_color(self):
        return self._color

    def set_color(self, color):
        self._color = color

    def del_color(self):
        del self._color
    color = property(get_color, set_color, del_color)
```

Here's the same example but using decorators instead.

```
class Train(object):
    def __init__(self, color='black'):
        self._color = color

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, color):
        self._color = color

    @color.deleter
    def color(self):
        del self._color
```

I've found that some like using the decorator syntax for read-only properties. For example.

```
class Train(object):
    def __init__(self, color='black'):
        self._color = color

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color
```

But the same functionality can also be achieved when saving to a variable.

```
class Train(object):
    def __init__(self, color='black'):
        self._color = color

    def get_color(self):
        return self._color
    color = property(get_color)
```

Two ways for the same functionality makes me confused since [PEP20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) declares

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Comment: I prefer the decorator syntax as it doesn't create extra methods that should never be called (but directly calling the `property()` function does) I'm not sure if this is the officially preferred method though.

Comment: The reason there are two ways is that decorators weren't introduced until Python 2.4, so before that, your first example was the only way. Decorators allow more readable code but the old way is still possible.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for explaining that decorators protect the methods so they're not callable like `Train().color('green')`. I will always use decorators from now on. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functionally, the two ways of doing this are equivalent. The decorator syntax is just syntactic sugar.

```
@some_decorator
def some_func():
    ...
```

...is equivalent to...

```
def some_func():
    ....
some_func = some_decorator(some_func)
```

The decorator syntax makes your code more cleaner (the non-decorator syntax means you have to type "some_func" three times!) and your intent more obvious, so I'd say definitely use the decorator syntax.

Comment: Thanks @tom! I will only use decorators from now on. One comment though, the non-decorator syntax can (and is [recommended](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)) to be written in a one liner. For example `color = property(get_color, set_color, del_color)`

Comment: Yes re: one-liner. But you still have to type each of [color, get_color, set_color, del_color] twice in the non-decorator syntax, whereas in the decorator syntax, you only type each of those once.